# MongoDB - How to delete documents which included in a list

Tags: python, database, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I want to delete documents from a collection which are not included in a list with Python.
All documents have a title field, and I have a list of the titles.

The list of titles is like below:

`titles = ["title1", "title2", "title3"]`

The documents in MongoDB are like below.

```
[
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "fsadkfds" },
    "title": "title1",
   },
   {
     "_id": { "$oid": "fasd;jklfdsma" },
     "title": "title2",
   },
   {
     "_id": { "$oid": "fdsjk" },
     "title": "title3",
   },
   {
     "_id": { "$oid": "klfdsjsdksf" },
     "title": "title4",
   },
]
```

In this case, I want to delete documents that have the title: title1, title2, and title3. In other words, I want to keep only title4.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to delete documents whose titles **are** in that list, or **aren't** in the list?  You say it both ways...

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I want to delete documents whose title ARE in the list.

Comment: Okay, so iterate over that list, search for any documents with matching titles, and delete them.  What is the difficulty?  Do you know how to iterate over a list?  Do you know how to search for a document with a certain title?  Once you have found the document, do you know how to delete it?

Comment: Have you tried: `collection.delete_many({ title: { $in: ["title1", "title2", "title3"] } })` https://pythontic.com/database/mongodb/delete%20documents

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you are using PyMongo, you should use [`delete_many()`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.delete_many) by providing the filter criteria to remove the documents.

```
db.collection.delete_many({ 'title': { '$in': titles } })
```